# Best actor, it is best to go there early..why “the” is omitted?

Tags: grammar, articles, superlatives

In many sentences I cannot find a reason why the definite article is omitted in superlatives, eg.:

It's best to get to the supermarket early.

He won the award for best actor, and deservedly so.

In thr first I guess it is because I do not compare “goings” to the supermarket, I simply describe one variant of that.
But in the second, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the adjective is not in front of a noun. So there is no noun to be made definite.

Compare

> He is the best dog.  (Best is an adjective, describing the dog)
>   He is the best.  (best is a noun)
>   He is best   (best is an adjective)

In the second case, it should be written

> He won the award for Best Actor.

Best Actor is the name of the award. Proper nouns don't generally require articles.